# Multiple api requests through axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, endpoint

I am building a restraunt web app which consumes Zomato api.
As soon as the component mounts and the browser detects location, axios starts making api requests in a loop whereas i just want to make **one single** request.
I just want to know the right place to call the function onSearchSubmit() which is actually responsible for making the API GET request.

Comment: your code is working properly...remove consoles... api call is correct as it should be in componentDidMount.

Comment: code is fine, I cannot see multiple call running locally.